# Is ~~ a short-circuit operator?

Tags: perl, operators, smartmatch

From the [Smart matching in detail](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.2/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) section in perlsyn:

> The smart match operator
>   short-circuits whenever possible.

Does `~~` have anything in common with [short circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (`&&`, `||`, etc.) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of short-circuiting here is that evaluation will stop as soon as the boolean outcome is established.

```
perl -E "@x=qw/a b c d/; for (qw/b w/) { say qq($_ - ), $_ ~~ @x ? q(ja) : q(nein) }"
```

For the input `b`, Perl won't look at the elements following `b` in `@x`. The `grep` built-in, on the other hand, to which the document you quote makes reference, will process the entire list even though all that's needed might be a boolean.

```
perl -E "@x=qw/a b c/; for (qw/b d/) { say qq($_ - ), scalar grep $_, @x ? q(ja) : q(nein) }"
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the sense that when one of the arguments is an Array or a Hash, `~~` will only check elements until it can be sure of the result.

For instance, in `sub x { ... }; my %h; ...; %h ~~ \&x`, the smart match returns true only if `x` returns true for all the keys of `%h`; if one call returns false, the match can return false at once without checking the rest of the keys. This is similar to the `&&` operator.

On the other hand, in `/foo/ ~~ %h`, the smart match can return true if it finds just one key that matches the regular expression; this is similar to `||`.